# Error writing Spark dataframe to CosmosDB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

I want to write a dataframe to CosmosDB.

`df_cosmos = spark.read.parquet('/some_dir/my_file.parquet')
config = {
  'endpoint': 'https://my-cool-endpoint.documents.azure.com:1337/', 
  'masterkey': 'my_secret', 
  'database': 'hello', 
  'collection': 'world', 
  'upset': 'True'}
df_cosmos.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**config).mode('append').save()`

Executing this leads to:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 198854.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 198854.0 (TID 3414976, 10.139.64.8, executor 7): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FilePartition.files()Lscala/collection/Seq;`

If I explicitly partition the dataframe something like
`df_cosmos = df_cosmos.repartition(1)` the the error is gone.

Im working in Databricks, with the following configuration:

- cosmos-connector: azure_cosmosdb_spark_2_4_0_2_11_1_3_4_uber.jar
- Cluster Version 6.1
- Apache Spark: 2.4.4
- Scala: 2.11

Changing the Cluster Version to 5.5, which results in Apache Spark 2.4.3 resolves the issue too.

EDIT:

I tested cosmos-connector with versions 1.4.0 and 1.4.1, but the results did not change

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were using the jar file [`azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-1.3.4-uber.jar`](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/microsoft/azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11/1.3.4/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-1.3.4-uber.jar) of Azure Cosmos DB Spark Connector for Spark 2.4 which comes from the offical docuement [`Azure Cosmos DB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector).

I'm afraid that's not suitable for the lastest version of Azure Databricks runtime like `6.1` and `6.2 Beta`.

According to the content of `README.md` of GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/) as the figure below, you may should switch to use the latest jar file [`azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-1.4.0-uber.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11/1.4.0/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-1.4.0-uber.jar) in it.

[image]

And the maven repo for [`Azure CosmosDB Spark`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark) has released to `1.4.1` version, as the figure below.

[image]

And Microsoft has moved its releases to https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cazure-cosmosdb-spark

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion. Meanwhile I tried different versions of the cosmos connector. I tested with 1.4.0 and 1.4.1, restarting the cluster on every try. But the result did not change.

Comment: Hi is there any solution to this issue I am also trying to connect latest databricks cluster. It failed to connect

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says - make sure the cosmosdb connector is the right version for the spark version. The documentation on the Azure CosmosDB for Databricks page needs updating. Use this instead: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/#working-with-the-connector

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If there is only a link you would like to add to an existing answer please use the comment function (as soon as you have the priviledge). In this way it does not really add anything new unless you explain what the content of the link describes differently to the answer already posted.